# Ubuntu live-USB does not start under MacBookAir3,1

Tags: ubuntu, mac, boot, macbook, liveusb

I downloaded Ubuntu here http://www.Ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download and followed step 2 to create a bootable USB flash drive. But when I restart my MacBook Air and press 'alt' during the restart process I cannot see the USB flash drive.

What I have missed?

Answer (score 0):

After holding down Option at boot and getting the graphical boot picker, if you saw a disk called something like "EFI Boot", that was probably your USB flash drive.